# Everything is working perfectly , but i dont know why the message is not sending

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, whatsapp

No errors and all nothing. it'll open the mentioned chat but dont know why it's not sending any messages.

```
target = '"Name"'

string = "Message sent using Python!!!"

x_arg = '//span[contains(@title,' + target + ')]'
group_title = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(( 
    By.XPATH, x_arg))) 
group_title.click() 
inp_xpath = '//div[@class="input"][@dir="auto"][@data-tab="1"]'
input_box = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(( 
    By.XPATH, inp_xpath)))
input_box = browser.find_element_by_class_name('_1Plpp')
for i in range(10): 
    input_box.send_keys(string + Keys.ENTER) 
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: We need more information to help you there. What exactly are you trying to do? What exactly is happening? What is supposed to happen?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
input_box.send_keys(string) 
input_box.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

maybe it is concatening string with string value of keys.enter